# How do I shift the report header to align with the page header?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My report has a report header placed in the report body before any data elements. The report also has a page header that appears on all pages except the first. The problem is, the report header, being part of the report body, begins below the header. I need it to start at the top of the page, at the top margin. The page header and report header contain a number and date in the same general location and switching between pages the 0.5 inch shift is noticeable and needs to be fixed. The desired fix is to shift the report header up on the first page 0.5 inch so the elements in common on the report header and page header overlay.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: can you provide screens in order to clearefy your question ?

Comment: You want to offset the top bit of the body (with something like a negative margin?) so it lands in the Page Header's location? Why not just place that tidbit inside the Page Header?

Comment: @Jeroen, ssrs wont allow anything to overlap, a feature i guess ;)

Comment: I must admit i cant quite get a handle on your issue, can you post an image or 2?

Answer (score 0):

I've interpreted your question as: *How do I shift the **top bit of the report body** to land in the page header?*

From your question I'd guess you want to shift something from the body upwards, so it lands in the Header region; possibly through a negative top-margin or top-location. **As far as I know this is not possible in SSRS.**

The solution seems simple (without further context or info about your data): place the things you want to show in the header *in the header itself* (instead of the body). If you don't want to show it on every page: use an expression. If that expression needs info from a dataset you'll have to create an internal parameter that is filled from a data set, because you can't access datasets in the header.

The real question is: *why* do you want this? Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): are you asking about your intended solution instead of the actual problem? Perhaps there's better ways to solve X. If so, and if you need help with that: be sure to post a follow-up question.